# `Function` does something bizarre with formal parameters

Tags: scoping, pure-function

I think this may overlap with existing questions, including one I asked years ago, but I'm not sure how, because the behavior I'm seeing is confusing enough I can't even really describe it except to say that Mathematica appears to be mixing up parameter names with symbol values in ways that seem to be flatly erroneous.

Out of an abundance of caution, I'm going to start here:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

Start with a use of select that does something pretty self-explanatory:

```
Select[{2, 3, a, b, 6, 7, c}, MemberQ[{a, b, c}, #] &]
(* {a, b, c} *)
```

Now, say we want to make this an anonymous function itself, abstracting over the first argument to `MemberQ`. One way that works is this:

```
Select[{2, 3, a, b, 6, 7, c}, Function[x, MemberQ[#, x]]] &@{a, b, c}
(* {a, b, c} *)
```

Now let's change the name of that formal parameter to `Function`:

```
Select[{2, 3, a, b, 6, 7, c}, Function[c, MemberQ[#, c]]] &@{a, b, c}
(* {2, 3, a, b, 6, 7, c} *)
```

Huh? Looking at a `Trace` with a minimal argument to `Select` sort of shows what's going on:

```
Trace[
 Select[{2, 3, a, b, 6, 7, c}, Function[c, MemberQ[#, c]]] &@{c}]
(*
 {(Select[{1},Function[c,MemberQ[#1,c]]]&)[{c}],
   Select[{1},Function[c,MemberQ[{c},c]]],
   {Function[c, MemberQ[{c},c]][1], MemberQ[{1},1], True}, {1}}
*)
```

I'm not sure what word to use to describe rewriting

```
Select[{1},Function[c,MemberQ[#1,c]]]&)[{c}]
```

as

```
Select[{1},Function[c,MemberQ[{c},c]]]
```

but "astonishing" is near the top of the list. It's neither lexical nor dynamic scoping. Nor does setting `"StrictLexicalScoping" -> True` have any impact.

I hesitate to call this a bug, but it is weird and puzzling.

Comment: That's not what I get when I trace. I see `Function[c, MemberQ[{a, b, c}, c]]`, and clearly this will always be true.

Comment: That was a copy'n'paste error on my party. Fixed in edit.

Comment: This is not a bug, in WL at least. Functions with `#` work like macros. Essentially you build the inner function at run-time: `Function[c, MemberQ[#, c]] &@{a, b, c}` -> `Function[c, MemberQ[{a, b, c}, c]]`, and this resulting one is the one that is used in `Select`. I think the key to remember about parameter passing in WL is that it works like macro-substitution, especially for functions with slots, or rules. Note that named arg `Function`s are more careful: `Function[lst, Function[c, MemberQ[lst, c]]][{a, b, c}]` -> `Function[c$, MemberQ[{a, b, c}, c$]]`, which is the result you want.

Comment: Perhaps one can summarize this by saying that that slot-based `Function`s are macros rather than (lexical) scoping constructs.